# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Searchbase'

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to return a list of members in a certain ou that belong to an active directory group. I am getting the error that:

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Searchbase'

Any ideas?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory


Get-ADGroupMember "Test" | -Searchbase "OU=US,DC=domain,DC=net"  | Format-Table Name
```

Comment: Try removing the pipe between your command and your parameter.

Comment: You may need to use -Searchbase with [Get-ADGroup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617196.aspx) and then select the member via Get-ADGroupMember afterwards. [Get-ADGroupMember Example 1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617193.aspx) has an example of this usage. (Examples are at the bottom of the page)

Comment: @HyperAnthony is correct since Get-ADGroupMember indeed does not have a -SearchBase parameter.

Comment: I tried this but I get another parameter error.Get-AdGroup -Filter * -Searchbase "OU=US,DC=domain,DC=net" |  Get-ADGroupMember "Test" | Format-Table Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example comparable to your described situation exists in the documentation for [Get-ADGroupMember - Example 1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617193.aspx), located towards the bottom of the page. In this example, we are getting the groups members of all domain local groups in the AD LDS instance:

```
get-adgroup -server localhost:60000 -filter {GroupScope -eq "DomainLocal"} -SearchBase "DC=AppNC" | 
get-adgroupmember -partition "DC=AppNC"
```

Notice how -Searchbase is a parameter of [Get-ADGroup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617196.aspx) instead of Get-ADGroupMember -- this allows you to get your group once in Get-ADGroup and simply pipe it into Get-ADGroupMember.  Piping from variables or other functions is fairly common in powershell, and useful because it keeps your operations separate and (in the case of variables) allows you to reuse results.

Comment: When I try this I get a popup to supply a parameter? get-adgroup -server localhost:60000 -filter {GroupScope -eq "domain"} -SearchBase "OU=US,DC=domain,DC=net" | get-adgroupmember "test"

Comment: For which cmdlet?  Could you paste the exception?